# Posting on a Group timeline where I am the admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-group

I am looking for a way to post on a group timeline where I am the admin.
I want to post from php and I want to post as the "group" and not as my personal user account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
You cannot post as "group" in group. Isn't possibile inside the facebook. That's possible only on facebook pages. You can create a facebook page and follow the instructions for post as "page".

here the instruction for [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

short summary:

> 1. Authenticate the user and request the manage_pages permission
> 2. Get the list of pages the user manages (https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
>
>    > The response will be an array of Pages and Applications that the user manages [...]
>    >     Within each block will be a Page access token or Application access token which can be used to make requests to the Graph API.

Comment: He asked about Groups, not Pages

Comment: @Igy is not possibile, inside the facebook, post a status as group name. Or i'm wrong?

Comment: You can post *to* a group, but not via the mechanism you listed in your answer - those are the instructions for managing a page. There is no way to post *as* (on behalf of) a Group

Comment: @Igy Yes, I think that He want know how post in a Page. He said "group" but also he said "timeline" and "post as admin". Group has not timeline and cannot post as "group"